# How do I achieve 100% [window] height on DIV on iPhone?

Tags: javascript, iphone, css, html

I've been trying to achieve 100% [window] height on a DIV for a project that I am working on. It works great in the desktop but when I try to load it using an iPhone 4 or an Android phone, the first div appears to be 100%; however each subsequent DIV appears to be about 50 pixels (just an estimate) short.

I tried setting it through css by doing the following:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;

    div#container {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
    }

    div#section1 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: blue;
    }

    div#section2 {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        background-color: red;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="container>
        <div id="section1">
            . . .
        </div>
        <div id="section2">
            . . .
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I also tried setting it through javascript with jQuery using something similar to:

```
var browser_width = $(window).width();
var browser_height = $(window).height();

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#section1, #section2").css("width", browser_width, "height", browser_height);
});
```

but it behaves the same way as the CSS. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the right format to the `.css()` method in your script

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#section1, #section2").css({
     "width" : browser_width, 
     "height" : browser_height
   }); //css
});
```

**UPDATE** : also I noticed you forgot to close your first css declaration

```
html, body {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
```

... the closing bracket `}` is missing.

**Side note** : I wouldn't set dimension properties to the `html` and/or `body` tags to avoid unexpected results ... unless you know what you are doing

Comment: The jQuery syntax is correct. You must use a comma. Not a semi-colon. I tried your suggestion and it broke the script.

Comment: @ChrisAmini yep my friend but you didn't notice I added brackets `.css({"":""})`. Your syntax using comma is valid when setting a single property, not multiple properties. Check [Example: To set the color of all paragraphs to red and background to blue:](http://api.jquery.com/css/)

Comment: You're right. I didn't see your comment. I tried this and the height doesn't seem to work at all with the variables. It also won't accept percentages. It works with a static integer just fine.

https://gist.github.com/4062203

Comment: ...another thing I noticed is that you are missing the opening `<html>` tag ... the script doesn't break the way I say, **[check this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tb32G/7/)** for a demo

Comment: regarding your github code, your variable declarations `var browserwidth = $(window).width;` and `var browserheight = $(window).height;` are missing the parenthesis `()` after `width` and `height`

Comment: I tried your code and it works great in the browser, however I am still getting the same results (as my original problem) on my iPhone 4 and on Android.

Comment: I discovered that the height property in jQueries CSS method doesn't work for me at all. Not sure what is going on. This may explain why I can't achieve 100% height.

Comment: @ChrisAmini you may have some js errors somewhere. I could help you better if you share a link with the issue